# Fetching Json array by proving Json object

Tags: android, json

Hello friends this is my json data:

```
{
   "menus":[
      {
         "id":15,
         "color":"#A67A37",
         "communications":[
            {
               "id":16,
               "projectname":"Sales Training",
               "showpdfprint":false,
               "sendcategory":"document",
               "opened":1
            }
         ],
         "seminars":[

         ],
         "name":"Selective Retail Academy"
      }      "communications":[
         {
            "id":17,
            "projectname":"Sales Education",
            "showpdfprint":false,
            "sendcategory":"document",
            "opened":1
         }
      ],
      "seminars":[

      ],
      "name":"Retail Academy"
   }
}
]
```

I want to retrieve communication Array providing name ,How can I achieve this in android

Comment: you can use GSON llibrary is very simple

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Using the org.json library:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonContent); //jsonContent is your content above as a string

JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("menus");
JSONArray result;
for(JSONObject jObj : jArray){
    if(jObj.getString("name").equals(givenName){ //givenName is the name you are looking for
        result = jObj.getJSONArray("communications");
    }
}
```

You can then do what you like with the communications JSONArray stored in "result."

You can see more on the org.json library here: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. this code help me lots, I edit this code like this                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjec.getJSONArray("menus");                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONArray Communications = null;
     String name = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
      if(name.equals(givenName)) {                                  Communications = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("communications");}

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Pseudo Code JSON Object](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_getJSONArray_.html)

Think that is Pseudo code for java